# ¿Porque no conecta a la Base de Datos?

Tags: java, mysql, java-swing

Cuando intento añadir algo desde java me dice que la conexion esta cerrada y no se que falla en mi metodo. Os dejo el accion performace del boton conectar y la clase conector.justo debajo del constructor tengo

```
private static ConectorBD mysql;
```

este es el accion performance

```
private void BtnConexionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        mysql = new ConectorBD();
        java.sql.Connection cn = mysql.Conectar();
        if (!cn.equals(null)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conectado");
            try {
                cn.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al desconectar " + ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Esta es la clase conector

```
public class ConectorBD {

    private String bd = "mundo";
    private String login = "root";
    private String password = "";
    private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/" + bd;
    private Connection conn = null;

    public Connection Conectar() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
            if (conn != null) {
                System.out.println("Conección a base de datos " + bd + ". lista");
            }
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
        return conn;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return conn;
    }

    public void desconectar() {
        conn = null;
        String mensaje = "La conexion a la  base de datos " + bd + " ha terminado";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mensaje);
    }
```

[image: Este es el error]

El metodo con el que da error es este :
Em la clase conexion tengo esto

```
public boolean existeContinente(String nombreC) {
        boolean existe = false;
        try {
            Statement orden = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet res;
            res = orden.executeQuery("SELECT count(Nombre) total FROM continente WHERE nombre'" + nombreC + "'");
            if (res.next()) {
                existe = res.getInt("total") > 0;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
        return existe;
    }

    public boolean altaPais(Pais p, String nombreC) {
        boolean flag = false;
        String nombre = "";
        try {
            if (existeContinente(nombre) == true) {
                Statement orden1 = conn.createStatement();
                orden1.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO pais(IdContinente,Nombre,Millones_habitantes) VALUES('"
                        + p.getIdCont() + "','" + p.getNombrePais() + "','" + p.getMillonesHab() + "')");
                orden1.close();
                flag = true;
            } else {
                Statement orden2 = conn.createStatement();
                orden2.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO continente(Nombre)  VALUES('" + nombreC + "')");
                orden2.close();
                Statement orden3 = conn.createStatement();
                orden3.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO pais(IdContinente,Nombre,Millones_habitantes) VALUES('"
                        + p.getIdCont() + "','" + p.getNombrePais() + "','" + p.getMillonesHab() + "')");
                orden3.close();
                flag = true;
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

En el accionperformance de añadir pais tengo

```
private void btnAñadirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        int id =  Integer.parseInt (jTID.getText());
        String nombreP = jTPais.getText();
        double habitantes = Double.parseDouble(jTHabitantes.getText()); 
        String nombreC = jTContinente.getText();
        Pais p= new Pais(id, nombreP, habitantes);
        mysql.existeContinente(nombreC);
        mysql.altaPais(p, nombreC);
        if(mysql.altaPais(p, nombreC) && mysql.existeContinente(nombreC) == true){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pais añadido");   
        } else if (mysql.altaPais(p, nombreC) == true && mysql.existeContinente(nombreC) == false){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El continente no exisitia y se ha añadido junto con el Pais");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al añadir");
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Puedes pegar la traza de la excepción que te tira? Y echa un vistazo a esto: `if (!cn.equals(null))` Esa comparación debería ser `if (cn != null)`, ya que tal y como lo haces, si cn es null, te  tiraría un `NullPointerException` al llamar a un método de un objeto nulo.

Comment: listo ya la tienes

Comment: Lo que me refería es el texto que hay detrás de la ventana que tienes en la consola en rojo (se ven unas pocas letras: Excepti...)

Comment: Lo de la consola es porque habia intentado hacer las cosas sin darle a conectar. En la consola solo sale run:
Conección a base de datos mundo. lista
Pongo el metodo que da error porsi es error del metodo que no creo